# what is the differences between r.Static() and context.File() to get the picture in gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm developing a Go program based on Gin web framework.

I want to serve pictures from the local file system.

[image]

```
func main() {
r := gin.Default()
r.Static("/page2", "resources/pictures")
r.GET("/test", func(context *gin.Context) {
    name := context.Query("name")
    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "name": name,
    })
})
r.GET("/page", func(context *gin.Context) {
    name := context.Query("picname")
    context.File("resources/pictures/" + name + ".jpg")
    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, "That is "+name)
})
r.Run(":9090")
```

}

I find it strange that when I use `/page2` to get the pictures (url `http://localhost:9090/page2/xiamei.jpg`), it works fine.

But when I use `/page` to get the pictures (url `http://localhost:9090/page/xiamei.jpg`) an error happens.

> http: wrote more than the declared Content-Length

What is the internal reason, and what is the root cause of the difference between these two access methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `/page` handler, you call both `Context.File`, and `Context.JSON`.

The first call to `Context.File` already writes the file to the response and sets `Content-Length` header.

By calling `Context.JSON` again with more payload, you are increasing the actual length of the content without updating the `Content-Length` header; this results in the error you see.

`r.Static` doesn't have this issue because it serves one file and doesn't add more payload than it should.

In a Gin handler you should call only **one** renderer function. If you are serving a file, you can remove the last `c.JSON` altogether.